# How do I get FROM/TO/CC and BCC using pypff?

Tags: python, email, pst

In pypff there is the attribute sender_name for messages, but I can't get the destinataries. Tried using message.trasnport_headers and parsing it, but it seems some messages don't have transport_headers (calendar, Teams, etc.)
I need to extract the destinataries for large PST files. Any suggestions will help!

Comment: Same for me. So still a relevant question.

Comment: @JohnDoe You can do this using win32com.client. Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58984562/14464956.